# Continuity of a map in topological spaces for closed subsets of the image

Tags: general-topology, education

I have been given this definition of a continuous function between two topological spaces. The definition states the following:

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a map between topological spaces $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}_Y)$. We say that $f$ is continuous if $\forall U\in\mathcal{T}_Y \implies f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal{T}_X$.

I was reading my notes and there is a proposition which doesn't have a proof in the notes and remarks that it is easy to prove. So I wanted to check whether I could prove it. The proposition is as follows:

$\textbf{Proposition}$: A map $f: X \to Y$ between topological spaces is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed in $X$ whenever $V$ is closed in $Y$.

Now I interpreted this proposition as such:

For a map $f:X \to Y$ and $V$ closed in $Y$, $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed in $X$.

I attempted to prove this and came up with something but I'm not sure whether its correct. The proof is as follows:

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose $f$ is continuous and since $V$ is closed then $Y \backslash V$ is open in $Y$ (by def of $V$ closed in $Y$). Now since $f$ is continuous therefore by the definition of continuous $f$, we have that $f^{-1}(Y\backslash V) = X \backslash f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. So $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed in $X$.

$\Leftarrow$ Suppose $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed in $X$ then $X\backslash f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(Y\backslash V)$ is open in $X$. As $Y\backslash V$ is open in $Y$ and $f^{-1}(Y\backslash V)$ is open in $X$ therefore $f$ is continuous. $\square$

Now my questions is whether this proof that I have presented is correct?

If it is not correct, where did I go wrong?

When I look at my proof, I doubt about the correctness of my last statement in the converse part of the proof. The definition of continuous function says, f is continuous if $\forall U \in \mathcal{T}_Y \implies f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{T}_X$. But that doesn't mean is if $ f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal{T}_X$ and $U\in \mathcal{T}_Y$ then $f$ is continuous i.e. if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ and $U$ is open in $Y$ then $f$ is continuous, right? Or have I completely misunderstood the definition?

Comment: That's correct. Taking preimages of sets plays nicely with set operations like complement, intersection, and union. The other direction does not work, which is why there are continuous maps that aren't open.

Comment: This is my first topology course so I don't know what an open map is, could you elaborate more a little more please?

Comment: An open map is a map $f\colon X\to Y$ for which, if $U$ is open in $X$, then $f(U)$ is open in $Y$. One might think that this is the same thing as being continuous, but it is not. A standard example is the function $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ where $f(x)=x^2$. This is continuous, but $f((-1,1))=[0,1)$ is not open.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much!

Comment: Continuity means that *whatever* open set of $Y$ you choose, its preimage is open in $X$. The closed set version says the same except for closed sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> For a map $f:X \to Y$ and $V$ closed in $Y$, $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed in $X$.

This suggests that continuity depends only on the inverse image of this set, which is nonsense;
the quantifiers are wrong, one could say, it **should** say (as in your first statement on open sets)

$$f \text { is continuous } \iff \forall C \subseteq Y \text{ closed }: f^{-1}[C] \text{ closed in } X$$

and the proof is as you sketched, using that complements and $f^{-1}$ combine well.

(so if $f$ is continuous and $C \subseteq Y$ is closed, $Y\setminus C \in \mathcal{T}_Y$ so continuity gives $f^{-1}[Y \setminus C] \in \mathcal{T}_X$ and as $ f^{-1}[Y \setminus C] = X\setminus f^{-1}[C]$, we have that $f^{-1}[C]$ is closed in $X$ as its complement is open. Going from this property to continuity is similar again).

So your proof was essentially correct, in short.